# PHP.ini Timezone not calculating correctly

Tags: php, configuration

I have set the timezone in the php.ini file to Europe/London. However the issue is when printing the date it doesn't  seem to be calculating Daylight Savings correctly. Could there be something I am missing.

Comment: I assume the date is correct?  May 19?  What do "echo date('T')", "echo date('O')", and "echo date('I')", yield?

Comment: Yes the date is displaying correctly as May 19th. Its purely just the time which is displaying as 15:27:16 instead of 16:27:16

T: BST
O: +0100
I: 1

Comment: Looks like you've done everything OK.  I'd probably ask the sysadmin at this point ... the system could just be wrong ...

Comment: The system time is displaying correctly. It just seems to be the PHP time. Wonder if this could be a PHP bug as its happening on multiple centos servers.

Comment: Does gmdate('r') yield a time one hour in the past?

Comment: Oh, and we're talking web app, right?  Restarted the httpd?

Comment: gmdate('r') displays a time 2 hours behind and yes a web app. apache and the server have both been restarted recently.